# want to delete file from both database n folder but not deleting form folder

Tags: laravel

```
public function deletePublication($publication_id=null){
    if(!empty($publication_id)){
        Publication::where(['publication_id'=>$publication_id])->delete();
        return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success','Publication Deleted Successfully..');
    }
}
```

by this code I'm unable to delete files from by folder which is inside public/files but files are deleted from database.Can You help me how can I delete files from both?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#deleting-files

Answer (score 1):

very simple try this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

public function deletePublication($publication_id=null)
 {
   if(!empty ($publication_id))
    {

     $publication_path = Db::table('publications')
     ->where('publication_id','=',$publication_id)
     ->value('publication_file');

     Storage::delete($publication_path);

    DB::table('publications')->where('publication_id', '=', $publication_id)- >delete();


        return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->with('flash_message_success','Publication Deleted');
    }
}
```

**path** it must be different in your table.
To know more about visit [File system Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#deleting-files)

Comment: this error comes ::SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'publications.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `publications` where `publications`.`id` = 1 limit 1)

Comment: i have modified my answer try now @shankarbhatt

Comment: i need to delete files from database as well as folder but your only delete  the file from database.Here I include migration file ->     Schema::create('publications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('publication_id');
            $table->string('publication_title');
            $table->string('publication_file');
            $table->string('publication_type');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: change this table->increments('publication_id'); to table->increments('id')
; and then try with Publications::findOrFail($publication_id);

Comment: if you don't want to change then the above answer i modified will work for you

Comment: ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined variable: publication      ->what we have to insert in values

Comment: use this: $publication_path = Db::table('publications')
     ->where('publication_id','=',$publication_id)
     ->value('publication_file');

Comment: why you  include publication_file and publication_path here

Comment: it will get the path for the file you store in the database

Comment: Storage::delete()
it accepts the file name or the file path.that's why we need to get the path of the file stored in a database

Comment: brother your code just delete the file in database but i need it must  delete file from the folder too!!

Comment: i need to access your code,because this code is working fine on my system.

Comment: public function deletePublication($publication_id=null)
     {
       if(!empty ($publication_id))
        {
    
         $publication_path = Db::table('publications')
         ->where('publication_id','=',$publication_id)
         ->value('publication_file');
    
         Storage::delete($publication_path);
    
        DB::table('publications')->where('publication_id', '=', $publication_id)->delete();
    
    
            return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->with('flash_message_success','Publication Deleted');
        }
    }

Comment: public function deletePublication($publication_id=null){
         if(!empty($publication_id)){
            $publication_path = Db::table('publications')
                ->where('publication_id','=',$publication_id)
                 ->value('publication_file');
            $file=$publication_path;
            $filePath =public_path().'/files/'.$file;
            unlink($filePath);
             Publication::where(['publication_id'=>$publication_id])->delete();
             return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success','Publication Deleted Successful) ~~It works bro!!

Comment: Cool.Enjoy your self.Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You just added the code to remove a file from Database. Need to remove the file from a folder, try below code

```
$filePath = 'public/files';
unlink($filePath);
```

Please read details of unlink() function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

You can also try from laravel to remove the file, please review the link from laravel documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#deleting-files

Comment: syntax error is showing where to place it .plz help me

Comment: Please try now. I forgot to add single quotes.

Comment: how can i delete five or six file  one by one with  this code

Comment: Please add make an array of delete file use it in foreach loop

Comment: how ? can you help me bro!

Comment: Means i dont get exactly. Try something in this way -->
   $array = ['filePath1','filePath2','filePath3']; foreach ($filePath as $file){ unlink($file); }

Answer (score 0):

What is your code to create a publication? What you did to create a publication (including the uploading of file), you also have to do the reverse (which is delete the file).

Laravel has a good documentation, you can refer to this link on how to delete files/directory: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem.

Comment: { public function deletePublication($publication_id=null){
        if(!empty($publication_id)){
            $filePath = 'public/files;
            unlink($filePath);

            Publication::where(['publication_id'=>$publication_id])->delete('public/files');
            
            return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success','Publication Deleted Successfully..');
        }
    }  } syntax error how to use  your code

Comment: $filePath = 'public/files;
unlink($filePath);     where to place this code in my code